# MySQL - maximum of sum over different months

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, max

I have a table called `commodities` where I have `nature_of_goods`column in it. `nature_of_goods` contains all the different types of goods like machinery, household etc.

I have another column called as `created at` which contains the date and time in timestamp format.

I need to find the maximum goods took place in particular month.

I have tried the following query:

```
select max(mycount)
from   (select   nature_of_goods, count(nature_of_goods) AS mycount
        from     commodities
        group by month(created_at));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY nature_of_goods`, if the counts should be separated by their values. To only show results of a particular month you have to put that in the `WHERE`, otherwise all months will be used.

Try something like this:

```
select max(mycount)
from   (select   count(nature_of_goods) AS mycount
        from     commodities
        where    month(created_at) = <insert desired month here>
        group by nature_of_goods) x;
```

.

Comment: I think she wants it for at least an entire year? So, it's a bit more tricky than that!

Comment: @Vérace: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I will edit or delete my answer, as soon as the OP states that my understanding was wrong.